# Is Vout in this circuit loop-grounded when Vin becomes 0V?

Tags: mosfet, ground

[image: plz refer to circuit below]

I don't have expertise in this area.
So any answer or instruction would be helpful to relieve my pain.

I think Vout would lose its GND when Vin becomes '0V' because C is located before GND.
Am I right? or wrong?

Comment: Could you please elaborate what you mean with "because C is **located before GND**"*?

Comment: I mean C is interrupting its connection to ground in a DC point of view.

Comment: For DC, the capacitor is *always* interrupting the connection of Vout to GND, **independent** of Vin.

Comment: My conclusion is this "Vout is floating when Vin becomes low" in accordance with Kevin's comment and Huisman's. Thanks a a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No - the output MOSFET will become open circuit when Vin is zero.

The output will be floating. The actual voltage at the output will depend upon the load. If there is something like a relay or lamp that conducts to ground the voltage will go to zero. As shown the capacitor C will charge up when Vin is a logic 1 and then retain its charge at 3.3v when Vin becomes zero.

This assumes that the threshold voltage of the MOSFET is adequately low to turn the device on with the ~3V available.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. You mean its output is not appropriate for driving load? cause it is not grounded when Vin '0' ?

Comment: Most loads do not require that they are grounded when the are turned off. So I wouldn't; expect there to the any issue. What is the load?

Comment: load is SOC which has a POR circuit inside such as MCU.

Comment: @GONGDOL - the SOC almost certainly does not require grounding when turned off. Think of what would happen with a simple single pole switch, it would not ground the output when turned off.